# RAM upgrade - confused with physical dimension - HP 15-af008AX Laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, computer-building, hp-pavilion

I have HP 15-af008AX laptop, it comes with in-built 4 GB RAM. It's very slow, I want to upgrade the RAM to 8GB. But I am getting confused with the physical dimension of the RAM. Some RAM lists physical dimension as - 7.3 x 3 x 0.2 cm
whereas other one has a physical dimension of 17.78 x 1.12 x 12.7 cm.

Can someone please tell me how do I figure out which size should I buy?

Options:
[Samsung 8 GB RAM DDR3](https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-original-204-pin-PC3L-12800-1600MHz/dp/B00I21G832/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=samsung%208gb%201600mhz%20ram&qid=1570027800&sr=8-2)
[Hynix](https://www.amazon.in/Sk-Hynix-Pc3l-12800s-1600mhz-Hmt41gs6bfr8a-pb/dp/B016Z5VB38/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=8gb%201600mhz%20ram&qid=1570027915&smid=A1QFJV05H9TXZX&sr=8-3)

Comment: Increasing the amount of system memory will NOT make your system faster.  Product descriptions on Amazon are not curated by Amazon.  **At least one of those product dimensions are actually incorrect.**

Comment: "Can someone please tell me how do I figure out which size should I buy?" - You have not supplied the vital but required information about your current hardware to make this determination.

Comment: You could measure your existing RAM card.

Answer (score 1):

A web search showed, as the first item, your laptop's [Product Specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04726782) which show your memory is in a 4 GB DDR3L-1600 SDRAM module. Therefore, you want a larger capacity [DDR3L-1600 SDRAM module](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=DDR3L-1600%20SDRAM&ref=nb_sb_noss_2).

Also, staying with the 5400 RPM SATA drive will also result in slowness. Using the instructions in your [Hardware Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04653881) to replace that with a [solid state drive](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=1%20TB%20SSD%202.5&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) will also speed up the PC because Windows is very disk-dependent.